# Why should (every? string? []) yield true?

Tags: clojure

Looking at the source code for `every?` makes clear *why*

```
(every? string? []) => true
```

This is because `every?` is implemented recursively and uses `(nil? (seq coll))` to end recursion.  But, my question is, what sense does this behaviour make?  Just tripped over that.

I have solved my issue using

```
(and (seq x) (every? string? x))
```

Comment: It is indeed true that every element of an empty vector is a string.

Comment: `every?` is written by a positive attitude person

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it functions the same as the forall-quantifier. That is, it is initially assumed true and each application of the predicate is an attempt to prove it false. The existential quantifier (which is called `some` rather than `any?` in Clojure for inconsistencies sake) works the opposite way - it assumes false and each application of the predicate is an attempt to prove it true.

In other words, it's always true that something is true for all of none, and it's always false that something is true for some of none.

Comment: Can you please link to a reference that explains how this makes sense? I assume this is Set Theory stuff, but it's not intuitive at all.

Comment: This has more to do with formal logic than with set theory (although you could introduce it in set theory). This is actually quite intuitive if you think about the negations like in Pawels answer - "something is true for all x in X" is the same as saying "there is no x in X for which something is not true". `every?` being false for empty seqs would also make quite a few expressions overly complicated.

Comment: Actually it is quite consistent that it's every? and some instead of any?. Every? can only return true or false, but some returns the first truthy (not nil or false) value, so it is not really a predicate.

Comment: @NielsK That's one way to rationalize it. I - and I think most other people - would expect there to be an "any?" if there's an `every?` though. That `some` behaves the same as a combination of "any?" and "find-first" is somewhat a gotcha, even if it makes sense with Clojures thruthiness policies.

Answer (score 8):

Function `every?` implements the [universal quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification).

From `(every? string? []) => false` it would follow that `[]` contains an object `x` such that `(string? x) => false` (this is how [negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#Negation) of universal quantifier works). This leads to contradiction, so `(every? string? [])` must return `true`.

Answer (score 7):

It is defined so in mathemathics an there is a good reason for that. It would be a consistency disaster if `every?` was defined any other way.

With current definition the result of concatenation satisfies `every? foo` if and only if all concatenated collections also satisfy `every? foo`. Making `every?` return `false` on empty lists would break this convenient equivalence and a host of others (e.g. removal of an element would sometimes lead to switching `every?` from `true` to `false`.)

Comment: I also like this answer for being "common sense" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or better ask why should `(every? string? [])` yield `false`? Both variants lead to wrong answer in certain requirements. But obviously it's better than get an error on empty sequence.

Comment: It might be obviously better to get an error on an empty sequence; it might not actually be better! We had some code blow up in production because of that very behaviour with, if i remember correctly, a fold in Scala. I'm not say that blowing up is wrong, just that there is some situation where any given behaviour will hurt you. Really, you want a type system powerful enough to stop you performing these operations on empty lists.

Comment: Yay for Haskell, which I appreciate and have learned from, but, I will stick to Clojure and try to deal with sometimes surprising issues like this :-)

Comment: @0dB It's not surprising at all if you're familiar with universal quantification, and I think even the Haskell folks would tell you that having different types for empty and non-empty lists is insane.

Comment: @Cubic Ouch, you are probably right, didn't bother to think about it :-)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).
Wiki covers it well so I'll simply quote the current first paragraph:

> In mathematics and logic, a vacuous truth is a statement that asserts
>   that all members of the empty set have a certain property. For
>   example, the statement "all cell phones in the room are turned off"
>   will be true whenever there are no cell phones in the room. In this
>   case, the statement "all cell phones in the room are turned on" would
>   also be vacuously true, as would the conjunction of the two: "all cell
>   phones in the room are turned on and turned off".

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to the identity values for the "and" and "or" operations. For any boolean B, it is the case that B has the same value as `B & T`. Thus, an "and" of no values must be true. Similarly, it is also true that `B | F` has the same value as B, so an "or" of no values is false.

In a similar vein, the product of no terms is 1 and the sum of no terms is 0, those being the identity values for the multiplication and addition operators.